# How to pick video file and play it via VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, libvlcsharp

So, how to select video file by `FilePicker` (result is `StorageFile`) and use the result to set source and play video file by `VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP`. The problem is following: I can get path but **not permission to the folder**. Only solution is pick the folder by `FolderPicker`, add the folder to the `FutureAccessList` and after that pick video file individually. So , hoping to find some other way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn... Answer was more near than first believed. Only what need to do is get a `stream` from `StorageFile` and use it... like following. Yeah, few cup of coffee help always!

```
VLCVideoView.MediaPlayer.Media = new Media(ControlLibVLC, new StreamMediaInput(await MySelectedStorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()));
```